# Can't find/activate Compiz 3d effects

Tags: compiz

I am new to Ubuntu and as the title says; searching through programs avalable it already checked out `OpenGL window and compositing manager` and `Compiz`, but nothing is found when searching through computer (search button) and i can't seem to find anything in system settings. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to install CompizConfig. I think you are looking for that.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/

Good luck!

Comment: Happy to help :)